# UrlEncoding giving different results

Tags: php, url-encoding

JavaScript function:

```
var s="ì";
var e=encodeURIComponent(s);
document.write(e);
```

Exspected result: %C3%AC
**Result**: %C3%AC

PHP function:

```
$s = "ì";
echo $e = urlencode($s);
```

Exspected result: %C3%AC
**Result**: %EC

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) clearly says that  LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH GRAVE (U+00EC) should be encoded as %C3%AC (i.e., using UTF-8), not as %EC (ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP file is likely encoded in a single-byte encoding, say ISO-8859-1. When you type in a non-ASCII character, it will use that encoding's representation of the character. You are expecting a UTF-8 (multi-byte) result.

To get that result, encode your PHP file as a UTF-8 file. Usually, your IDE will have an option for this; often in the "Save As..." dialog.

Alternatively, if you can't or don't want to change your file's encoding, you can do

```
echo $e = urlencode(utf8_encode($s));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot got it! Will mark your answer as solution once im able to.